# What is the current state of research about the Hayden-Preskill circuit?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, ads-cft, matrix-model, black-hole-firewall

Can someone summarize as to what are the problems and/or the open questions with the [Hayden-Preskill circuit](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hayden+preskill)? (in the context of understanding black-holes or as a computer science question)It gives a framework to see how the black-hole can thermalize in a $log (entropy)$ time scale. What next?

To start off,

The sort of problem with the Hayden-Preskill circuit is that it works via random unitary transformations on disjoint pairs of qubits and hence doesn't have an Hamiltonian interpretation. I believe one has always believed that matrix models (of matrix size $\sqrt{entropy}$) can saturate this logarithmic thermalization bound via Hamiltonian evolution.

- Has this above belief about the matrix models been proven yet?
- Is there an intuitive explanation as to why a theory with finite dimensional matrices should behave like an infinite dimensional system?

Comment: This is a repost of [this closed question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126193/about-the-hayden-preskill-circuit). The previous closed question has been deleted so only high rep users will be able to see it. You will not make friends and influence people by just reposting verbatim a question that has already been closed.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think you are confusing something - what was closed was an earlier form of the question which had only the first line or two of what is written here - after the moderators closed that question, on my own I deleted that question and then reposted it with the additional details.

Comment: Hi user6818. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.